# Get First Non-null Value From Selected Rows For Every Column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query that can get First Non-null value for selected columns from the table. 
I cant fire multiple queries and union it per every column as I have so many columns. I tried to create a query using answers form some SO questions. but it doesn't work for me.

**Example Table**

```
| orders| id   | default_address |
|-------|------|-----------------|
| 1     | 1    | null            |
| 2     | null | null            |
| 3     | 2    | 3               |
```

---

**Expected Result**

```
| id | default_address |
|----|-----------------|
| 1  | 3               |
```

---

**Another Example Table**

```
| orders| id   | default_address |
|-------|------|-----------------|
| 1     | 1    | null            |
| 2     | null | 5               |
| 3     | 2    | 3               |
```

---

**Expected Result**

```
| id | default_address |
|----|-----------------|
| 1  | 5               |
```

What i tried is here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84a5c/1

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/574481/2

Comment: Why would you want to get data corresponding to different data points in a single row?

Comment: Rows don't have any built-in ordering, you need a column to order by. Is there a column like that in your table?

Comment: yes. i have but cuurenty i can use id

Comment: There's nothing built-in that will do that. And if you need to do it for lots of columns, you'll need to repeat the query for each column and merge them. You could write dynamic SQL that gets all the column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: @Ravi You can't use `id` since it has `NULL` values, which aren't ordered.

Comment: To elaborate on Barmar's comment, you need to show us a _third_ column which generates the ordering shown in your sample data.  Without that, we can't give you an answer.

Comment: okay. let me edit for ordering for example @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using analytic functions, assuming you are using MySQL 8+:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(id) OVER (ORDER BY orders) cnt_id,
        COUNT(default_address) OVER (ORDER BY orders) cnt_addr
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN cnt_id = 1 THEN id END) AS id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cnt_addr = 1 THEN default_address END) AS default_address
FROM cte;
```

This assumes that there actually exist a third column `orders` which generates the ordering shown in your sample data.

This trick works because the `COUNT()` function by default only counts non `NULL` values.  So, used a window function with the ordering given by the `orders` column, it would only equal 1 at the *first* non `NULL` value.

For earlier MySQL versions:

```
SELECT
    MAX(id) AS id,
    MAX(default_address) AS default_address
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(t2.id) FROM yourTable t2
                   WHERE t2.orders <= t1.orders) = 1 THEN id END AS id,
        CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(t2.default_address) FROM yourTable t2
                   WHERE t2.orders <= t1.orders) = 1 THEN default_address END AS default_address
    FROM yourTable t1
) t;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm having lower MySql version than 8.0. so WITH doesnt support i guess.

Comment: Updated for earlier versions of MySQL.

Comment: Great. Its Working.

Comment: stil having an issue as I have so many columns if you can help. I appreciate.

Comment: My answer should work with any number of columns, but I don't know of a way to avoid pivoting for each column, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: is there any another way coz this will not work for huge data amount.?

Comment: Well you could implement a trigger which keeps track of the first non `NULL` value for each column, and store those values in another table.